# PHP Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: php, oracle

I was given a task of fixing an app after the update.

Presumably, the person who updated it said they updated it to 'Oracle 12c' - whatever that means, **thought the path is: 'C:/oracle/product/11.2.0/'** which sounds like it's still 11.2.0 or whatever.. not important.

Whenever I'm trying to run `oci_connect();` with verified and tested credentials, the error pops:

`Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol`

I've searched around the internet, found 2 solutions:

- download and add 'ojdbc8.jar' to 'C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib' **(hope the path is correct)**.
- add the lines below to 'sqlnet' which I found in:

  - 'C:\oracle\product...\network\admin\' and
  - 'C:\oracle\ora92\newtork\ADMIN'
  - **I've changed in both to be

  sure**.

```
The lines:
    SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8
    SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8
    SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
```

Same result, neither worked.

## Edit:

I've also noticed, there's no `oradmin.exe` nor `oracle.exe` in the bin folder, is this normal?

Comment: If you're using PHP, then downloading the JDBC driver is not going to fix anything.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What do you suggest?

Comment: I guess you need to use a newer version of the OCI library, but I don't use native libraries for Oracle, and don't program in PHP, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server is updated and now the client fails to connect.  In this case the server needs to configured to allow older client to connect.  Add the SQLNET parameters to the server sqlnet.ora file and restart the server.

Comment: As I said in the main post - I did, didn't help.